# Javascript "Sat Feb 15 2020 14:01:19 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)" type of date format in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am migrating my app from Angular/Ionic/firebase (although am still keeping this frontend version in production) to Dart/flutter/firestore. So two frontends one database(firestore).

I have a database in firebase that has a date parameter which is generated by a `Date()` function on the javascript frontend. It is stored like this in the database: `"Sat Feb 15 2020 14:01:19 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)"`.

I want to migrate my database (with its data) from firebase to firestore but remain consistent with the way the date is stored.

I have looked into Flutter's `DateFormat()` and `DateTime()` but I have failed to see a way of creating this type of date format or a library that reads it.

Any help!

Comment: first convert the date from that format to UTC timestamp using your server side script. Then pass the UTC timestamp to flutter app so that flutter can understand UTC timestamps.

Comment: @Darish my dilemma is how to save such a date `"Sat Feb 15 2020 14:01:19 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)"` to firestore generated from flutter like I would generate it from js.

Comment: you can pass the timestamp from flutter to your server API, and with in the server API you can convert the timestamp into your required format.

Comment: @Darish OK, given that I am using firestore and not yet that advanced in firebase/firestore, how can I achieve this?